# Unable to force eclipse kura to listen on ipv4 interface

Tags: eclipse, debian, ipv6, beagleboneblack, kura

I am trying to setup kura on beaglebone black. kura version is 1.4.0 and OS is "Debian GNU/Linux 8".

I installed the ".deb" file from kura website. But after successfully installing, I could see that kura is listening only on the ipv6 interface:

```
 root@beaglebone:~# sudo netstat -plan | grep java                                                                                               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      12796/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::5002                 :::*                    LISTEN      12796/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::1450                 :::*                    LISTEN      12796/java      
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     485514   12796/java          
unix  2      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     489190   12796/java          
root@beaglebone:~#
```

[This](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/963542/) kura forum post says that I need to disable ipv6 support in the kernel using sysctl to force kura to use ipv4. But this did not work for me. And I could not see any option in kura's "config.ini" file to configure this.

Problem is that my network does not support ipv6. So I need ipv4 itself.

But this seems like a common requirement. Kura should either enable ipv4 by default or should allow ipv4 configuration right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, netstat is showing the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. This does not mean that IPv4 addresses are not supported. Please see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152612/netstat-why-are-ipv4-daemons-listening-to-ports-listed-only-in-a-inet6) for more information. In fact, it is the opposite, Kura does not support IPv6.

Based on your output of netstat, Kura is listening on port 80. Did you change this in the config.ini file? If so, you have to make sure all the default BeagleBone web services are disabled. Generally, for the BBB, it is better to allow the default port of 8080. There is a general [BBB getting started guide here](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/beaglebone-quick-start.html).

For further debugging, please provide the following:

- Any errors in /var/log/kura.log or /var/log/kura-console.log
- Connect to the OSGi console with:

  ```
  telnet localhost 5002
  ```
- From the OSGi console, post the output of the 'ss' and 'ls' commands

Thanks,
--Dave